# Is there an OpenOffice.org glossary for users?

Tags: openoffice, users

[OpenOffice.org>DevGuide>Glossary](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Glossary/Glossary) defines terms for developers. Is there an OpenOffice.org glossary for users with terms such as Macro and Template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [OpenOffice .org glossary](http://plan-b-for-openoffice.org/glossary/index)